# How to configure the process open file limit of a user?

Tags: process, limit, open-files, ulimit

The default open file limit per process is 1024 on - say - Linux. For certain daemons this is not enough. Thus, the question: How to change the open file limit for a specific user?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Linux you can configure it via [`limits.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf), e.g. via

```
# cd /etc/security
# echo debian-transmission - nofile 8192 > limits.d/transmission.conf
```

(which sets both the hard and soft limit for processes started under the user debian-transmission to 8192)

You can verify the change via:

```
# sudo -u debian-transmission bash -c "ulimit -a"
[..]
open files                      (-n) 8192
[..]
```

If a daemon is already running, it has to be restarted such that the new limit is picked up. In case the daemon is manually started from a user session, the user has to re-login to get the new limit.

Alternatively, you can also specify additional limits directly in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, of course - but I prefer the `.d` directory approach for better maintainability.

For enforcing different soft/hard limits use two entries, e.g.

```
debian-transmission soft nofile 4096
debian-transmission hard nofile 8192
```

(rationale behind this: the soft value is set after the user logs in but a users process is allowed to increases the limit up to the hard limit)

The `limits.conf`/`limits.d` configuration is used by `pam_limits.so`, which is enabled by default on current Linux distributions.

### Related

There is also a system-wide limit on Linux, [`/proc/sys/fs/file-max`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

> This file defines a system-wide limit on the number of open files for all processes.

For example the default on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
$  cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
786046
```

The pseudo file [`/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) provides more information, e.g.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
1408    0   786046
```

> the number of allocated file handles (i.e., the number of files presently opened); the number of free file handles; and the maximum number of file handles

Thus, on the one hand, you also may have to adjust system-wide `file-max` limit, in case its is very small and/or the system is already very loaded. On the other hand, just increasing `file-max` is not sufficient, because it does not influence the soft/hard limits enforced by the pam_limits mechanism.

To change `file-max` on the command line (no reboot necessary):

```
# sysctl -w fs.file-max=786046
```

For permanent changes add `fs.file-max=786046` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d`.

The upper limit on `fs.file-max` is recorded in [`fs.nr_open`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt). For example, (again) on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
$ sysctl -n fs.nr_open
1048576
```

(which is 1024*1024)

This sysctl is also configurable.

Comment: Thank you for the last bit of information - I was scratching my head trying to figure out why I couldn't set a user nofile limit greater than 1048576 in /etc/security/limits.conf